# Criação de tabelas Sqlite(Room) no Android com o padrão repository (Pergunta bem simples.. mas preciso de um esclarecimento)

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

Pessoal eu tenho uma dúvida na criação das tabelas e outra na questão do repository, então vamos lá.

EX:

```
data class Carro(
    val marca: Marca,
    val motor: Motor
)

data class Marca(
    val nome: String
)

data class Motor(
    val potencia: Double
)
```

A questão é: 1) Terei que criar três tabelas no sqlite uma para cada objeto? Duas com o segundo e o terceiro? Uma única para carro contendo tudo?

2. Utilizando o padrão repository e o viewModel. Quando eu criar a classe que implementa o repository, pelo que entendi, terei que passar os DAOs para o construtor desta
   EX

   ```
     class DatabaseDataSource(

         val carroDAO: CarroDAO,
         val marcaDAO: MarcaDAO,
         val motorDAO: MotorDAO

     ): InterfaceExemploRepository {

    override fun insertCarro(carro: Carro){
          marcaDAO.insert(carro.marca)
          motorDAO.insert(carro.motor)
          carroDAO.insert ????
    }

    ....outras funções CRUD.....
   ```

   }

Obviamente este exemplo não está correto e só foi criado com o propósito de explicar a questão, quem puder me dizer como seria a maneira correta ficarei muito grato.

Em um problema real se utilizar esse conceito de um DAO para cada tabela, em classes com muitas dependências (5 ou 10 objetos) terei que passar todos esses DAOs para o repository? Essa é a uma boa prática?

Obrigado a quem puder me ajudar